# How to retrieve respons status from Street View Image Metadata using guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle, google-street-view

I am using guzzle to call to **Street View Image API** from my laravel application. I want to be able to retrieve the status code from my request as explained in the end of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata).

I specifically want to catch the:

```
{
    "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

here is my Guzzle code from my controller (am including guzzle correctly in namespace). The address in the get call is generating a "Sorry we have no imagery here":

```
$client = new Client();
        $res = $client->get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x600&location=78.648401,14.194336&key=my-API-key&fov=120&heading=90');
        $res->getStatusCode();
        dd($res->getBody());
```

BUT. As u can see in the pic the meta-data is empty. When I dd the *$res->getStatusCode();* it gives me a **200**.

How do I catch the ZERO_RESULT ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sir, please note that there are two different endpoints; one for metadata and one for image retrieval. You only used the image retrieval. Here is an example method checking if a given coordinate has an image

```
private function coordinateHasImage($coordinate)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->get(  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?size=600x300&location=' . $coordinate . '&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE');
    return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents())->status == "OK";
}
```